# using expression tag in javascript code not getting expected output?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

```
'<%=messages.getString("16359")%>+"("+counterstarttest+")"';
```

The output should be a string where counterstart test is also a dynamic variable but it is not behaving as such

I am getting

Start Test +"("+counterstarttest+")"'

Comment: If `counterstart` is a Java variable it should be included between `<%=` and `%>` as well.

Comment: no, it is a javascript variable and this peace of code is a part of javascript function

Comment: Then why do you expect it to be expanded? It is part of a string. I *think* (but a bit of context would make this easier to answer) it should be something like `'<%=messages.getString("16359")%>' + "(" + counterstarttest + ")";` then.